# Is there a word for the person that's giving the promise?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

For example, if I said, I promise I will do something. Is there a word for me? Promise giver?

Is there a one word noun for this?

Comment: Vower; , and also in legalese promisor/promissor

Comment: You are "sworn".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Promiser** seems to be a valid word:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Promiser

> Noun  1.  promiser - a person who makes a promise

Additionally, the word **promisor** means the same thing in a legal context:

http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/promisor

> PROMISOR. One who makes a promise.

Comment: Is this an actual word? It didn't come up in a lot of dictionaries. Is there not a more elegant word for it? Not to say promiser isn't elegant, I was hoping for something different

Comment: I also found 'promisor', which is used for legal circumstances

Answer (score 2):

**a pledger** seems to be what you're after:

Example from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pledge :

> ‘Even so, the local authority would be aware of the statistics of the
>   American programme, from whence they get their inspiration, and its 88
>   per cent failure rate amongst pledgers.’

Answer (score 1):

You could say that if you are a promise-giver you are **avowed**.

(As the **avower** you are **sworn**)

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/

Comment: Hello, PCARR. This is potentially a very solid answer, but at the moment it lacks the reinforcement of a cited dictionary definition or other reference-work corroboration.  Please consider adding something of the sort to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is **[guarantor](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/guarantor)**.